# error with std::array and VS2015

Tags: visual-c++

I have code that I wrote quite a while ago, and I don't do that much 'C++' these days. I've compiled the code with no issues in 'Visual C++ 2010 Express'. I've compiled it in vs2015 and I get an error with the 'std::array'. Could someone be kind enough to explain my error.

This compiled ok in 'Visual C++ 2010 Express'

```
// create arrays to hold port write data​
array<DataChunk>^ dataArray = gcnew array<DataChunk>(1008);
```

But compiled in vs2015 with the error:

```
1>c:\users\carl\desktop\pond control\pond control\Form1.h(1199): error C2976: 'std::array': too few template arguments

1>  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility(306): note: see declaration of 'std::array'
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: ^ or \*: array<DataChunk>* dataArray

Comment: try: array<DataChunk, 1008>;

Answer (score 1):

[std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is a container data type that encapsulates "regular" fixed-size arrays. You need to provide the array size as a template parameter:

```
auto dataArray = gcnew array<DataChunk,1008>();
```

Comment: I've tried that and it comes up with 'Error:incomplete type is not allowed', at the array declaration after gcnew.

Comment: I've installed VS2013 and it compiles ok in that. It must be the libraries in the vs2015 ?