# C++/CLI std::array has changed since VS2010?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli

I have a working VS2010 solution that has a C# program passing an array to a C++ DLL using this syntax:

In the C++ file:

```
void MyClass::MyFunction( array< Byte >^% byteArray, unsigned int size )
```

Where the first parameter is a pointer to the array and the second is the number of elements in it.

In the C# file I call this function like so:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
byte[] bArray = new byte[8];
myClass.MyFunction(ref bArray, 8)
```

This all works.  But I am now trying to port the code to a VS2015 solution and the C++ code is failing to compile.

In the C++ project VS puts a red squiggle under the trailing `>` in the function definition, and the message seems to be `too few arguments for class template "std::array"`

My guess is that either the std::array template definition changed between VS2010 and VS2015, or the compiler itself changed (and is now more strict)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30395498/error-with-stdarray-and-vs2015) seems to back up my guess and points that the `std::array` needs an additional size parameter.  However I am trying to pass in an array of an arbitrary size.

So my question is: can I achieve the same functionality in VS2015? If so, how?

Comment: You can try with `cli::array< Byte >^% byteArray`

Comment: @Hackerman Well that gets rid of the syntax error!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, `std::array<T,n>` absolutely is a fixed-size container. However, as you might have noted, you don't actually say `std::array`. This points at the actual problem: you used *another* `array` in VS2010, a definition that is now hidden by `std::array`. That is almost certainly caused by `using namespace std;`, something that is widely discouraged.

Fix: remove `using namespace std;` and use `std::` where you mean it.

Comment: Except I am not `using namespace std`.  But I do accept that I am probably not using `std::array` in my VS2010 solution

Comment: @PeterM: Well, the error message is rather clear that you're using `std::array` when you write `array`, so that means you either have `using namespace std` or `using std::array` _somewhere_ prior to that error. Could be in a header, though.

Comment: Ok I had to go back 3 levels of includes before I found it, but yeah I see the `using namespace std` now.  The mystery to me is why I didn't have this issue in VS201

Comment: @PeterM: You might not have an explicit `#include <array>` but implementations are allowed to include one header from another. VS2015 probably has different header dependencies.

Comment: I did eventually find https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx#BK_STL so I suspect that that is the case.

Comment: @PeterM `using namespace std;` in a header is a recipe for huge problems. By the way, `cli::array` has a `Length` member, you don't need to pass the size separately.